# How to get the string of a json child in a json array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, android-studio

I will like to get the value of a JSON string in a JSON file the string is nested in a JSON array I am using android studio here is my JSON file

```
{
  "Amber":
    {
      "Info": {
        "name": "Amber",
        "bio": "Turkish-Cypriot",
        "image": "null"
      },
      "Class": {
        "Adorable": {
          "name": "",
          "link": ""
        },
        "IronAge": {
          "name": "",
          "link": ""
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I will like to get the value of name and bio to a string here is the java code i have tried

```
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public class AsyncHttpTask_GetWebData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                if (result != null) {
                    String response = streamToString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    parseResult_GetWebData(response);
                    return result;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Loaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to Data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private String streamToString(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String line;
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
        if (null != stream) {
            stream.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void parseResult_GetWebData(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Amber");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject =jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Info");
                String name = jsonObject1.optString("name");
                textView.setText(name);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The textview is empty and not showing the result but i am getting the OnPostExecute toast saying the Data is loaded successfully but the value is not displaying in the textview

Comment: According to the error message, I think it has nothing to do with `JSON` or your subject.

Comment: but i have use this same block of code to parse other JSON data

Comment: i have edited the question but now am not getting any result i.e the textview is not showing any data

Answer (score 0):

firstly, I suggest you use the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to convert the `Json`.

Secondly, the `JsonArray` is for the following format:

```
"arrary_key": [
            {
                "name": "Jeff Bridges",
                "id": "162655890",
                "characters": [
                    "Jack Prescott"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Charles Grodin",
                "id": "162662571",

            }
]
```

so the second it is still a `JsonObject`

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject jsonObject = response. getJSONObject("Amber");
```

or you can ask the service to  return jsonArray